# How to preserve the query string while using add_rewrite_rule and default public query vars

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a single page application embedded in a WordPress website. I'm able to redirect back to that page with a rewrite that matches the page slug as a base:

```php
add_rewrite_rule( '^showroom/?', 'index.php?pagename=showroom', 'top' );
```

and the optional URL route parameters are maintained and used by the application (ex. `/showroom/mercedes/` loads the page and shows the correct showroom. `/showroom/mercedes/sedan/` loads the page and the correct showroom and category.)

Things break down with URLs that include a query string. To simplify route matching, I add page and keyword search variables as query parameters. It appears that because I use the same names as the default WordPress query vars (`page`, `search`) they are included when the query is built, and the result is that if I try to include `?page=2` in one of these URLs I get bumped back to the base application URL.

Changing the names of the query string variables to things like `offset` or `keywords` "solves" the issue but I'm curious if there is some kind of hook or alteration I could make to my rewrite expression that would preserve whatever query string the user provides.